# D3: Update Data Down the DOM

Tags: d3.js

I am having trouble updating the **data** attribute on child nodes in the DOM. I am using SVG and binding an array of data to parent group ('g') elements. The groups then contain a circle and some text. When I first create the circles the data from the parent 'g' is automatically passed in and bound to the circle. What I can't figure out is how to update the data on the child 'circle' nodes when I update the data on the parent 'g' elements.

Here is an example to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
var test = svg.selectAll("g").data([1,2,3,4]);
test.enter().append("g");
test.append("circle");
```

I now have the following DOM:

```
svg -> g (__data__ = 1) -> circle (__data__ = 1)
       g (__data__ = 2) -> circle (__data__ = 2)
       g (__data__ = 3) -> circle (__data__ = 3)
       g (__data__ = 4) -> circle (__data__ = 4)
```

Now I want to map new data:

```
var test2 = svg.selectAll("g").data([9,8,7,6]);
```

Which gives the following DOM:

```
svg -> g (__data__ = 9) -> circle (__data__ = 1)
       g (__data__ = 8) -> circle (__data__ = 2)
       g (__data__ = 7) -> circle (__data__ = 3)
       g (__data__ = 6) -> circle (__data__ = 4)
```

I can't figure out how to have the child circle nodes inherit the data values of their parent g-elements.

I've tried things like the following without success:

```
test2.selectAll("circle").data(function(d) { return d; })
```

and

```
test2.selectAll("circle").data(function(d) { return this.parentNode.__data__; })
```

Does anyone have suggestions how this is accomplished?

Comment: If you only have a single circle in each `g` you can do `test2.select("circle");` which will propagate the data.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer as well.

Comment: Lars, can you point me to anything in the d3 docs that explains why this works?

Comment: Sure, see the link in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`.select()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-select) operator, in addition to selecting a single element, also propagates the data from the current element to the selected element. You can use this for your purposes if each `g` element only contains a single `circle` element by running

```
test2.select("circle");
```

This won't work as nicely if there's more than one `circle` though, as you would need to select each of them individually.

Comment: Thanks, I'd missed that select binds the ancestor data to the child. If you have a moment: It also seems to me that 'test2.selectAll("circle").data(function(d) { return d; })' should have worked... Is there a simple explanation for why that doesn't?

Comment: This only works when the data you bind to the parent element is nested, e.g. an array of arrays. At the lower level, one of the nested elements would be bound. See the [nested selections tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) for an example use.